# How is a blade coated in salt for demon slaying?

Tags: weapon, demons, castlevania

Salt is often used to repel demons and I've seen several sources talk about coating blades and other weapons in salt so they can slay demons, most recently in season 1 of Netflix's Castlevania.  How is salt applied to a blade?  Does it stick if you just rub the edge of a blade with a handful of granulated salt or is some other method required?

Comment: Cut a fresh lime in half and rub it on the edge of the blade.

Comment: In general, it would be a horrible idea, since the salt would keep falling/rubbing off the blade, especially after hitting the target. One probable solution would be placing a special "poison grove" in the blade itself and apply salt in the form of a paste.

Comment: @Blackwood - And add tequila? And ignore the demons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed in the Castlevania episode Monument. Apparently it's sufficient to simply rub your blade with salt, enough of it adhering to make it an effective weapon against a demon.

> I want salt over here! As much as you can find! Everyone with a sword wipes their blades in the salt.

[image]

Comment: It looks kinda like a salt paste or thick syrup rather than grains (looks very liquidy... ok, it looks like icing.  salt icing. runny salt icing). I wonder if that has an effect on the adhesion, etc of salt to the blade.  Then again, it might just be the animation making it look like that

Comment: @Megha - It appears to just be table salt in a bucket. I doubt they've done anything to it

Comment: it looks sloshier than table salt to me, but then again I'm not familiar with the source, just what I'm seeing in this tiny clip (which is also colored by the question context), so there may well be other interpretations.

Comment: @Megha - That's just the animation style...